# Cannot perform dist upgrade

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I'm getting the following error when trying to run `sudo apt dist-upgrade -y` and upgrade from 22.04 to 23.04

```
Calculating upgrade... Error!
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgweather-4-0 : Breaks: gnome-calendar (< 43~) but 41.2-3 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

What should I do to fix the break?

Comment: The command `apt dist-upgrade` does **not** change you from one release to the next, the most if can do is go from 22.04.1 to 22.04.2 (ie. you'll remain a 22.04 system, just with upgraded packages) so your situation is confusing.  You've also tagged your question to be about a 20.04 release? so please clarify what OS/release you're asking about.

Comment: FYI:  The only package version listed in your paste is `gnome-calendar | 41.2-3                  | jammy           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` which isn't a 20.04 package you tagged, and doesn't relate to *lunar* or 23.04 so please clarify (23.04 will use `44.1-0ubuntu1`)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full and unaltered outputs of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Tag me in a comment @nmath once you've finished adding this information

Comment: Your output plainly states that you have installed wrong-version packages onto your system. You fix the problem by either reverting the packages to the version compatible with the rest of your system or by uninstalling those packages. The use of `dist-upgrade` to jump from 22.04 to 23.04 is not tested nor supported, so be prepared for more problems that you must solve yourself.